# Clearcase Base and UCM downloads only Foundation Baseline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to download the latest Baseline code with Base ClearCase and UCM ClearCase plugin in Jenkins. But both plugin supports only Foundation Baseline to download.

Is there any way I can get the Latest Baseline Code from ClearCase through the same Base ClearCase plugin or else I need to know how I can do a rebase from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how I can do a rebase from Jenkins ?

With a classic [`cleartool rebase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm), as [you did before in August](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45492560/6309).
You would call that command from a build step in your job, in order to update the ClearCase view Jenkins workspace set by Jenkins (initially to a foundation baseline, which is not what you want)

But any rebase would only work if the stream selected in the Jenkins UCM plugin is an Integration one (the first of an UCM project). If it was a development or build one (ie a children of the main Integration stream), you might rebase only baseline from the immediate parent.

If you are on an Integration stream, then you can list all the baselines of a component: see "[List the latest baseline of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309)".
Then, if the latest one is not the current one (see "[can't read the foundation baselines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053610/6309)"), you would perform the rebase.